# App crashes when passing Dictionary in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, nsdictionary, segue

So, I've done this a million times, but today, it seems like my brain has come to a halt and I'm completely stuck on this... Here it goes:

I've got to pass a JSON responseDict to a CollectionViewController via a Push Segue. The response is a timeline feed from Instagram.

In my sourceVC the Dictionary is defined like this: `var timelineResponse: [String : AnyObject]?` and in my destinationVC the response Dictionary is defined the same way `var responseDict: [String : AnyObject]?` Although I've tried to define it all sorts of way to see if that was the problem.

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            if (identifier == "photoSegue") {

                //This println correctly outputs the contents of the dict, so I know that the dict is not nil before passing it.
                println("sending timelineResponseDict to PhotoCollView with following data: \(timelineResponse)")

                  // I've tried the following two methods of passing the dict to my PhotoCollView
//                (segue.destinationViewController as PhotoCollectionView).responseDict = timelineResponse!

                let toVC: PhotoCollectionView = segue.destinationViewController as PhotoCollectionView
                toVC.responseDict = timelineResponse!
                toVC.stringResp = "Test"
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to pass a test string, to see if that worked, which it did. So it seems to be the Dictionary type it doesnt want to pass along. But why?

**SOLVED**

I was trying to pass type `AnyObject` to a Dictionary, and hence the crash. Sorry for wasting a bit of time here! :/ I appreciate the comments guys!

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint to figure out what's the line throwing the exception - it would be good to know which one, although I suspect it's where you force unwrap `timelineResponse`

Comment: @Antonio By trial and error, and by breakpoints I've concluded that it is the passing of the dict that's responsible for the crash. I've tried without force unwrapping as well, but with no results

Comment: what message do you get in the crash? What's the exception?

Comment: @cmyr 0 swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional

Comment: Is it possible that `timelineResponse` isn't set?  You are force unwrapping it but you don't check that it isn't nil first.  Also double check that `segue.destinationViewController` is actually a PhotoCollectionView